# smslib (Sudden Motion Sensor) for Mac is not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm trying to develope capture device orientation with **smslib** (**Sudden Motion Sensor**) on macOS **mojave**, but it seems not to be working.

**smslib**
http://www.suitable.com/tools/smslib.html

I tried smsutil command on README, but output is 'Error: couldn't start SMS'

```
./smsutil -i0.01 -c1000 -atxyz -s09 >capture.txt
```

Because this project is very old and may as well not support mojave.
Does anyone know how can I work this on mojave or any other way to capture device orientation of mac?

Comment: Is it that it fails on Mojave? Or on that particular device? It is quite likely that most recent Apple notebooks (particularly those shipping with only SSD - not HDD - option) do not have the requisite hardware (SMS) anymore

Comment: Oh, I see! It fails on SD device. I didn't know that SSD device doesn't have SMS. Thanks a lot !!